# 'Planned appointments' and 'Performed appointments' in the same or separate tables?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

Let's say I am making a database for a car repair shop. (Using MySQL).

A person can book an appointment to get their car repaired - so the table would contain the following fields...

```
appointment_id
time_created
appointment_time
```

To record the service itself I would need some additional information...

```
employee_id (Who fixed it?)
time_performed
```

Should I create a single table and have 'employee_id' and 'time_performed' initially null or should they be split up into separate tables? How have you handled similar problems in the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either would work, but it seems that it would fit better to have a single table.

Each appointment would normally end up having service information added to it, so if you have separate tables you would end up with pairs of records that are just inconveniently separated into two tables.

If you would have frequent appointments that doesn't result in service, or if it would be possible to do more than one service on one appointment, you would naturally use two tables.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP it seems that you need the following:
A table `Car` a table `Person` and a table `Mechanic`.
The `Car` and `Person` has a `1-1` relationship while the `Car` and `Mechanic` has a `1-M` relationship since a `Car` is serviced by `1` `Mechanic` while a `Mechanic` can service many cars

Comment: That would be missing a table to store the occurance of an appointment and a service. That can't be stored in the Car or Mechanic table, as one car can have multiple services, and even be serviceD by the same mechanic more than once. I think that you are thinking of objects being physical, while abstract things like an appointment or a service can be an object just as well.

Comment: @Guffa:Relatioships can have attributes and the appointment and service are attributes of the relationship `serviced-by` between `Car` and `Mechanic`

Comment: Not with a `1-M` relationship. You need a `M-M` relationship, otherwise a mechanic could only ever service a car once.

Comment: @Guffa:A mechanic services a car once on a particular date

Comment: Yes, and if you have a `1-M` relation, then that mechanic can never service that car ever again. You need a `M-M` relation, so that you can add one relation for each service date.